# openSUSE Leap installation fails

Tags: linux, system-installation, dual-boot, opensuse

I am trying to install a Linux distro without any success. The hard drive's current OS is Linux Mint although I usually boot into Windows 10. I have also tried installing Ubuntu and Arch Linux with the same problem: I do not get a fancy user interface and whenever I click *Install* my screen goes black and sometimes the PC reboots. I suppose it has to do with my external graphics card which is an Nvidia GTX 970 OC. My questions are:

1. Is that a common problem with a fix to it that I haven't found?
2. Is the support for newer hardware that bad on Linux? and of course
3. Does anyone know to fix it?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS mode?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `nomodeset` parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

1. Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a boot menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the boot menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the boot menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> is unnecessary.

[image]

2. Press the <kbd>e</kbd> key to edit a menu entry. This will bring up an **openSUSE Leap** screen that looks like this:

[image]

3. Use the arrow keys to navigate when screen editing the above screen. Navigate to the line on this screen that starts with `linuxefi`.
4. Replace `splash=silent` by `nomodeset splash=silent`. This change is only temporary — it will just be used once and GRUB won’t remember it in the future. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with the `nomodeset` option that was added. If you make a mistake, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to the previous screen.

To make the change permanent you need to add it to the `/etc/default/grub` file. Append `nomodeset` inside the quotes of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."`. Then update your grub settings with `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from running with `-nomodeset` option off.  When arriving at the welcome screen enter `f1` to get to the advanced welcome screen.  After enter `f6` to select `-nomodeset`.

For more details and discussion see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262451)

Comment: thanks for the answer. unfortunately I don't get the interface you think i get. I am greeted with few options to choose by arrow buttons. The only other buttons that react are E (for some strange properties) and C for a grub console.

Answer (score 0):

I also had what sounds like the same issue.  I expect you have resolved it by now.

I pressed Fn'5 to change the kernel settings and chose 'No ACPI' which did the trick for me.